# Access parent and its parent

Tags: c++, arduino

I am having difficulty getting a child class to be able to reference its parent. 
Here is a fresh and simpler code example:

```
class AlphaClass {
public:
    AlphaClass(){}
    ~AlphaClass(){}
    void init() {
        alpha++;
    }
    int alpha = 0;
};

class BetaClass : public AlphaClass {
public:
    void init() {
        beta++;
        alpha++;
    }
    int beta = 0;
};
```

Compiler output:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Warning     In file included from       D:\Documents\Arduino\DesendentTest\Beta.cpp 5
Error       14:1: error: expected class-name before '{' token       D:\Documents\Arduino\DesendentTest\Beta.h   14
Error       19:4: error: 'alpha' was not declared in this scope     D:\Documents\Arduino\DesendentTest\Beta.h   19
Warning     In member function void BetaClass::init()       D:\Documents\Arduino\DesendentTest\Beta.h   -1
Warning     alpha++
```

Comment: You should add the compiler error you get. Also why did you make the destructor purely virtual?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I got rid of the destructor, but no change. The compiler errors are added above:

Comment: I was asked by @xaxxon to provide a "Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example." That is exactly what I was trying to do. I don't appreciate the patronizing lecture. I take what I am doing seriously and ask for help only when I am stuck. I respect helpful answers and responses.

Comment: the code you've posted seems to work fine in a "normal" compiler.   It is fine C++: https://godbolt.org/g/nkNADe  I don't know what the compiler you are using is complaining about.

Answer (score -1):

The problem stems from the abstract constructors and destructors. When I removed all "virtual" keys, it works fine:

```
class FooBar {
    public:
        char foobar[7] = { 'f','o','o','b','a','r' };   //  Should be publically visible
        FooBar() {
            Serial.println("\nConstructing FooBar");
        }
        void begin() {
            Serial.println("\nFrom FooBar:");
            Serial.print("foobar=");
            Serial.println(foobar);
        }
    };

    class Foo : public FooBar {
    public:
        const char foo[4] = { 'f','o','o' };

        Foo() {
            Serial.println("\nConstructing Foo");
        }

        void begin() {
            Serial.println("\nFrom Foo:");

            Serial.print("foo=");
            Serial.println(foo);

            Serial.print("FooBar=");
            Serial.println(FooBar::foobar);
        }

    };

    class Bar : public Foo {
    public:
        const char bar[4] = { 'b', 'a', 'r' };

        Bar() {
            Serial.println("\nConstructing Bar");
        }

        void begin() {
            Serial.println("\nFrom Bar:");

            Serial.print("bar=");
            Serial.println(bar);

            Serial.print("foo=");
            Serial.println(foo);

            Serial.print("FooBar=");
            Serial.println(foobar);
        }
    };

    FooBar *foobar;
    Foo *foo;
    Bar *bar;

    void setup() {
        Serial.begin(115200);
        Serial.println("Beginning...");

        foobar = new FooBar();
        foo = new Foo();
        bar = new Bar();

        foobar->begin();
        foo->begin();
        bar->begin();
    }

    void loop() {

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to duplicate your results.